# Can I connect MySQL to Access AND host it online for two people to use remotely?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have two people who want to use the database I created, which means 2 connections from remote locations. Can this be done?

I've recently come across an article citing numerous problems with using MySQL as a back end for Access, would I be better off just building an access database, and if so, could I still host it online for 2 people to use?

Comment: following the comment from Yvette you can read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the configuration you have in mind is:

- put your MySQL database on a server that allows direct connections to MySQL from the Internet,
- define a MySQL ODBC DSN for that database on each of the two remote machines, and
- install an Access front-end with ODBC linked tables to access the MySQL database over the Internet.

If so, then you *can* do that, but you probably don't *want* to. The Access front-end will "talk" to the linked tables as if they were on a local LAN connection, and depending on the complexity of the Access application and the speed of the Internet connection between the clients and the MySQL server the results could range from "a bit sluggish, but usable" to "so slow as to be unusable".

With recent versions of Access the "recommended" way to share an Access database over the Internet would be to convert the database tables to SharePoint and then create an Access "web database". However, that would be a lot of work for just two users.

One other option would be some sort of remote desktop solution like Terminal Services, but again that could turn out to be fairly expensive (in time and money) for just two users.